# How to solve woocommerce product stock management - add to cart value problem?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, inventory-management

In woocommerce after creating a product when i click to set stock manage for that product and define the maximum value to ex(100) [here is the image where i set the value to 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wwmz1.png)
now when i save and preview that product the default add to cart buy product should be 0 or 1 and it is shown 100 and the add to cart + - to add product does not work so the customer will have to buy 100[here is the img for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsvg4.png)
now when i manually edit the numbers of the product ex(10) and click to add to cart
than a msg saying [value must be 100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc1U2.png) now when i look at the html through console than this html is shown

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity_630e359d05759" class="input-text qty text" step="1" placeholder="0" min="100" max="100" name="quantity" value="4" title="Qty" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" aria-labelledby="Bollywood Classics 1 (Copy) quantity">
```

By some error the minimum quantity is set to 100 in backend and which is causing this problem.
please help me solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

Please check with default WordPress theme if all working fine then may be issue with current theme

Comment: I have checked and still can't find the issue. So if you would like to check yourself and solve the issue we are willing to pay. Please contact me 6398134610 as soon as possible